# How can I retrieve the address pointed to by a pointer address?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory

Consider the following:

```
int pointer = 0x0066D378;
```

How would I go about retrieving the address pointed to by that pointer address in the memory of another program? Remember, not the address of "pointer" variable, that pointer address belongs to another program, how can I get the address from that in its current context (from the memory of aforementioned program)?

Cheers !

Comment: In the memory of another process? The OS doesn't allow that. Why would you need that?

Comment: @dcastro In the context that my program is hooked into that program. Would "Injecting" be the right word? If so, I mean that. And I'm playing around with two programs I made, testing the effects of changing memory etc, would that be possible?

Comment: Take a look at `ReadProcessMemory`/`WriteProcessMemory` API functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx respectively).

Comment: @Dennis What variable type should the result be assigned to?

Comment: @Daaksin: these API functions operate with raw byte arrays. So, you are responsible for interpreting read or write operation result.

Comment: Do you want cross-process communication? If so, you should be using named pipes.

Comment: @dcastro Well.. I'm reading/writing data from programA to programB, does that count? Even if does... 0 idea what Named pipes are...

Comment: Named pipes allow two processes to communicate with each other and exchange data. Naturally, both processes need to know about this pipe, so they can both 'connect' to it. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: @dcastro It possibly could, where can I find documentation on these things? Also, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inter-process communication (which seems to be what you need to solve your problem), you can use either anonymous pipes or named pipes:

Anonymous pipes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx
Named pipes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx

The operating system takes care of sending messages from one process to another.
If both processes run on the same machine, I'd recommend using anonymous pipes as they are lightweight.
If they're on different machines on the same network, named pipes are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Test this. p value will be the address of the testT string assigned to int i first and then assigned to p as a i's value.

```
    private static string testT = "test line to have an address";

     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Test(testT);
    }

    static unsafe void Test(string str)
    {
        fixed (char* pfixed = str)
        {

            int i = (int)pfixed;
            int* p = (int*)i;
            int* c = p;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I need the address pointed at by a pointer in the variable testT. And the target pointer is in another program..